# Liferay - how to get assetentry subtype in velocity template?

Tags: templates, liferay, velocity

my asset publisher is displaying two types of **Web Content Article Subtype** (asset publisher->configuration->asset selection->asset type->web content article subtype->select more than one...).

I need to get subtype of asset entry to create a right structure based on entry subtype, something like:

```
#if (!$entries.isEmpty())
    #foreach ($curEntry in $entries)
        $curEntry.getSubtype()  
    #end
#end
```

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use liferay services in VM like example in below link
http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Access+to+Liferay+services+in+Velocity

Go through Asset Publisher Portlet -> configuration_dynamic.jsp it has the code which gets the subType you require i.e. Structure created in webcontent.

Other way to get the structure for webcontent is using DDMStructureLocalService it has getStructures() method where you can pass webcontent (i.e. journal class id)

Hope it gives you the direction to achieve what you are looking for.